# Como faço pra retornar a data?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return(
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> this.setState({isItemVisible: true, modalData: {...item}})}>
            <View style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                flex: 1,
                marginLeft: 25
            }}>
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>{item.period}h</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex: 2, marginLeft: 5, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'black', textAlign: 'justify'}}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <MaterialIcons name='keyboard-arrow-right' size={20} />
                </View>
            </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    }
```

Meu item.period vem da api e quero retornar ele apenas o dia do mês que está lá

Comment: Qual é o valor atual dele?

Comment: Ele me retorna a data em HTML

Comment: Quero saber qual o valor está vindo no seu objeto. Se tá vindo `2019-01-01 11:22:33`, ou `25/1/2019 00:00:00 PM`, etc.

Comment: "period": "2019-10-17T00:00:00.000-03:00",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer direto na renderização pode usar assim:

```
<Text style={{color: 'black'}}>{new Date(item.period).getDate()}h</Text>
```

Ele vai te retornar o dia do mês como você deseja, no caso da entrada ser como seu exemplo `"period": "2019-10-17T00:00:00.000-03:00"` vai retornar `17`

Comment: Deu cert, obrigado

Comment: @RuanDuarte, já que a minha resposta te ajudou a solucionar o seu problema, então se você não tiver mais nenhuma dúvida, poderia por favor aceitá-la? Caso ainda haja alguma dúvida ou algum ponto a esclarecer, me diga por favor para que possamos esclarecê-la.